# File input instant upload techniques?

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, frontend

**Context:**

I setup a photo upload that uses an iframe to upload the image, then that has an optional jCrop step.

**the client** doesn't want to have to wait for the image to be uploaded. here's what the client said:

```
"You shouldn't have to wait for anything on the server end. 
I don't care if the cropping happens on the server or client. 
The interaction for cropping shouldn't wait on upload"
```

Is the client crazy, or is there some kind of way for me to have the image available for front-end manipulation instantly?

Edit:

**TLDR:** using a `<input type="file"/>`, if a user picks an image, can I *immediately* reference that local file somehow? would that show up as the input's value after change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three technics to do a browser based image manipulation possible:
- java applet
- flash
- html5: file api (to read the image) and canvas (to show and manipulate it). But the browser support for the file api is not quite good as far as I know.